# Is there any monitoring tools to create scenarios/dependencies check?

Tags: monitoring, system-monitoring, healthcheck

My team and I got the project to test a new monitoring solution that allow us to :

- Perform classical monitoring checks (through SNMP, ping, sensor status, vendor librairies etc...)
- Perform checks in chain or healthchecks, like a scenario, for instance => check a switch interface + check server status + check database query + check app status => red/orange/green alert.

We're currently using Eye Of Network (based on Nagios/Grafana), it's very complete but it doesn't allow to create checks in chain, i also tried PRTG, it seems it doesn't have the functionnality.
Meanwhile, in a different project, we're testing Dynatrace since weeks but it more APM oriented.

I don't know if such a solution exists or if we'll have to go for a custom solution.

Thanks a lot for your advices guys.

Comment: Have you tried Zabbix? It allows to create triggers with complex metrics which highly customizable.

Comment: https://www.zabbix.com/

Comment: I heard about Zabbix but i didn't know it allow such functionnality. I'll give it a try ;) Do you know if the custom part is user friendly or not ? (the plan is to allow different workers to create scenarios, so skills may vary from one to another)

Comment: You can use Zabbix API in order to automate some tasks, additionally create templates and autodiscovery for easy maintaing hosts inventory :)

Comment: Additionally, it has got regularly updated montoring templates for popular devices.

Comment: Will you accept my answer if I post it here?
Please feel free to ask any questions about Zabbix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Zabbix](https://zabbix.com/) perfectly fits your needs.

- It can perform classical monitoring checks (SNMP, ping, etc.)
- You can create complex triggers based on metrics.
- Additionally, you can create customized actions for different alerts.

Comment: Thanks ;) i'm already having a look (currently installing) ! thanks Marat !